# grep error on redirection

Tags: cygwin, wget, grep

I want to extract urls (matching a pattern) from a file & download them. Here's my egrep expression (on Cygwin) :

```
egrep -o -e "http([^\"]*)filter=[0-9]+" myfile.html
```

This works fine until I try to use a redirect or pipe. Example :

```
egrep -o -e "http([^\"]*)filter=[0-9]+" myfile.html > tmp.html
```

OR

```
egrep -o -e "http([^\"]*)filter=[0-9]+" myfile.html | wget -i -
```

Error  : 
`egrep: >: No such file or directory`

I think the error is due to the backslash before the quote but I've tried escaping it. Doesn't work.

Comment: What does `type egrep` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it and it succeeded for me with `CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39`:

```
Fisherscreek@Fisherscreek-PC ~
$ egrep -o -e "http([^\"]*)filter=[0-9]+" myfile.html >/tmp/out.txt

Fisherscreek@Fisherscreek-PC ~
$ cat /tmp/out.txt
httpZADfilter=42
```

I wonder if you've got a Bash alias gone haywire.